# In Gnome, what signal on dbus-monitor indicates the user is logging out?

Tags: gnome, dbus

I want to write a script that runs in the background and detects when a user logs out. I am having trouble finding documentation on dbus-monitor. The best I can do is that I see a flurry of `EndSessionQuery`, `EndSession`, and `EndSessionResponse` but these all come with booleans so they can't fully be trusted (maybe a program says it doesn't want the user to logout?) and on top of that, what if no programs are open? This is too unreliable.

What I want is to listen for a signal that will always happen when the user is logging out. Can someone provide that signal? Currently I am running this command:

```
dbus-monitor --session \
    "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | \
        myprog
```

which catches the ScreenSaver events. But I also want to catch logout. What I wish for is something like:

```
dbus-monitor --session \
    "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.Session',member='LogoutSuccess'" \
    "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | \
        myprog
```

Comment: Have you looked at what is being sent on the system bus during log out? Console-kit will maybe send something: sudo dbus-monitor --system

Answer (score 4):

Look for the files called org.gnome.SessionManager.* here: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-session/tree/gnome-session

There is a SessionOver signal in the interface org.gnome.SessionManager that may be what you need.

Are you looking for the normal "session is ending, quit yourself or put up a prompt or something" request from the session manager, or a "session is really ending now, bye bye" signal?

Comment: I'm looking for the "everyone decided to quit. this is really happening." signal.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken.  The "this is really happening" signal is "Stop" from org.gnome.SessionManager.ClientPrivate - see gnome-session/gnome-session/gsm-dbus-client.c:dbus_client_stop().

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but I'm adding some info in case anyone else needs it.

I had the same needs, but ended up implementing a Session Manager DBus client as an easy to use script. It executes a user-defined script on logout. The ready to use application is shared on GitHub.

[Gnome EndSession DBus client](https://github.com/backloop/gendsession)